# Suppress logging of module

Tags: python, logging, python-module, python-logging

I'm using the umap-learn module (pip install umap-learn). I'm importing the module with `import umap`. Everytime I call the `transform()` method of this library the following information is logged to the console:

```
Batches: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  1.96it/s]
```

I already tried to add `logging.getLogger("umap").disabled = True` but it does not work.

How can I suppress the logging of this module to the console?